# background-image doesn't appear when using media query

Tags: css

I'm attempting to replace one image with another, and I know a common way is to shift one image and use a background-image. Unfortunately it's just showing completely blank for me when I do this.

Here's a code pen showing what I mean:

https://codepen.io/TheNomadicAspie/pen/JjWVbKJ

And here's the relevant CSS. Any ideas?

It's returning a 403 forbidden error when I check the console.

```
#main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
        'chat_bubble character_image'
        'button_menu character_image';
    grid-template-columns: 5fr 1fr;
    place-items: center;
}

#chat_bubble {
    grid-area: chat_bubble;
    width: 70vw;
    height: 70vh;
    padding-left: 2vw;
    padding-right: 2vw;
    padding-top: 2vh;
    padding-bottom: 2vh;
    margin-bottom: 1vh;
}

#character_image {
    grid-area: character_image;
    margin-top: 2vh;
}
#character_image > img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

#char_1 {
    display: inline-block;
}

#button_menu {
    grid-area: button_menu;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    gap: 1em;
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
    #main {
        grid-template-areas:
            'chat_bubble chat_bubble'
            'button_menu character_image';
        grid-template-columns: 4fr 1fr;
    }

    #character_image > img {
        height: 100px;
        max-width: unset;
        padding-top: 100px;
        background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/sRSVW2D.png') !important;
    }
    
    .container:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        top: unset;
        right: unset;
        left: 75%;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border: 0.813em solid transparent;
        border-top-color: #ffffff;
        border-bottom: 0;
        border-right: 0;
        margin-left: -0.406em;
        margin-bottom: -0.812em;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using background-image in media queries, change src of the image on screen resize.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', ()=>{
    if(window.innerWidth > 700) {
       image.src = 'firstimage.jpg';
    } else {
       image.src = 'secondimage.jpg';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [content: url()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) as

```
    #character_image > img {
        height: 100px;
        max-width: unset;
     /* padding-top: 100px; */
        content: url("https://i.imgur.com/sRSVW2D.png");
    }
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/KaungKZ/pen/YzZovqN)

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me on Codepen, but on my actual code it didn't. I tried using file names as well as url, but I couldn't get it to work the same way as on Codepen. I ended up using Javascript to do it as suggested by the other answer, but I appreciate you trying to help. The code works, just not on VS Code for me for some reason.

Comment: Glad you found the answer ! Keep in mind that you might also need to check `innerwidth` of the browser every time a user enters website. Because if a user enters with screen size smaller than `700px`, image is not gonna change as user hasn't resized the browser.

Comment: Ahh, I wonder if that was the problem. I'll try that out and see if it works. I'm happy with the JavaScript solution for now but I would like to find out what I was doing wrong to avoid problems in the future. Thanks for the tip.